# XML RPC Wordpress hook

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to add a function that would be fired on a new xml-rpc request in wordpress.
I'm using a plugin for that, but it seems like nothing that I write there is actually changing anything and I don't even know how to debug it since I can't var_dump or output anything.
This is my code:

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_methods', 'mydealz_xmlrpc_methods');
function mydealz_xmlrpc_methods($methods)
{
    $methods['myMethod'] = 'mydealz_xmlrpc_function';
    return $methods;
}

function mydealz_xmlrpc_function($args)
{

    wp_insert_term(
      'Baseem', // the term 
      'size' // the taxonomy
    );
    wp_mail( 'mymail@gmail.com', 'var_dump', 'fasdghfdsah' );

}
```

Thanks a lot!